# How to play .MP3 URL in Xmarine MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, android, http, https, android-mediaplayer

We are working with Xmarine MediaPlayer to play an simple .MP3 through URL. But we are unable to access my "https" website URL but can access "http" website. I have used the below mentioned code. Please suggest what to do.

```
> MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(); player =
> MediaPlayer.Create(this,
> Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.EXAMPLE.com/TEST.mp3"));
> player.Start();
```

Comment: which errors you get? Do you have valid SSL certificate on your site?

Comment: Yes, I have SSL cirtificate in my site. I got "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in android media play" error

Comment: show full stacktrace. Also format your code properly

Comment: `Button.Click += delegate
{
try
{
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.EXAMPLE.com/TEST.mp3"));
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
string a = ex.ToString();
}
};
`

Comment: edit the question and put the code there. And show the full exception stacktrace

Comment: can you play an array of byte file in media player rather than a link?

Comment: I was trying to run https link, I did not tried with array of bite. I have to do it via URL. it is project requirement.